# Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on edittext

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to show datepicker popup window. I have found some examples but i am not getting it properly. I have one edittext and i want that when i click on edittext the datepicker dialog should popup and after setting the date, the date should show in edittext in dd/mm/yyyy format. PLease provide me sample code or good links.

Comment: hope it will help for multiple edittext too. https://gist.github.com/pratikbutani/036e73e26139096e3b0ba91f85e23d85

Answer (score 830, accepted):

Try this in the XML file:

```xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Birthday"
    custom:font="@string/font_avenir_book"
    android:clickable="false" 
    android:cursorVisible="false" 
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:hint="@string/birthday"/>
```

And this in the Java File:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final Calendar myCalendar= Calendar.getInstance();
    EditText editText;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.BirthDate);
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date =new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
                updateLabel();
            }
        };
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,date,myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateLabel(){
        String myFormat="MM/dd/yy";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        editText.setText(dateFormat.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Add `android:focusable="false"` within the xml file of the `EditText` to allow for a single touch.

Comment: Can You tell me what is that new_split.this?

Comment: @JEMSHID56 new_split.this means classname.this that is new_split is current class name

Comment: This did not work for me. :( I had errors I did not know how to get rid of with the updateLabel method.

Comment: Well I just copied the code above into my setupUI method, and the updateLabel() method has errors I dont know how to solve. Im sure this is because it is inside of my setup method. But when I move it outside of this method I am having run time issues.

Comment: EDIT: I solved this problem. Just had some scoping/declaration issues. This worked great!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on the first click (which focuses the EditText).

Comment: use editText.setOnFocusChangeListenerinstead, works on first click

Comment: Dont know why but my onDateSet method is not called once I change the date any help

Comment: @DanielJonker editText.setOnFocusChangeListener is giving the calendar twice..I have 3 calendars in a page.when edittext is clicked it shows up the calendar on first click but it is again giving the previous calendar..

Comment: I've solved this by using `android:focusable="false"` and `onclicklistner`

Comment: I also needed android:focusable="false" and I had to declare and define the edttext inside updateLable(). Very Nice!

Comment: @KevinMiller if you define the `EditText` right below the public class of the current activity not within the private `onCreate()` you are not required to redefine it.

Comment: Probably want to set `android:longClickable="false"` too. Otherwise the user can bring up the paste option on the field (and thus enter invalid dates).

Comment: Be sure to use `if(hasFocus)` in `setOnFocusChangeListener` otherwise calendar will trigger multiple times

Comment: @Prabs If you use `android:focusable="false"` when the user hits "next" in the keyboard when focusing a View before the date, the focus will jump directly to the one after the date. The best solution is to use both `editText.setOnFocusChangeListener` and `editText.setOnClickListener` and keep the `EditText` focusable. This way "next" is going to work and it's gonna popup in the first touch either.

Comment: True @Gustavo Is there any other alternative to stop the calendar from opening twice?

Comment: @Prabs I put the `DatePickerDialog` in a variable and before calling `.show()` I checked `.isShowing()`. This way I always use the same dialog.

Comment: This is a useful solution. I would appreciate if you can tell the methods for (1) setting the date picker non-cancellable. (2) setting a title on the top of the date picker.

Comment: using edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener instead onClickListner is better for many reason
for exemple when you need to click next button on the keyboard

Comment: `android:editable` is deprecated. I fixed this issue by adding `android:cursorVisible="false"`, `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Comment: Date has had a shorthand version of the `.set` function since API Level 1. You can shorten within the function to `myCalendar.set(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);`

Comment: I don't know how everybody favors that focusChangeApproach. It's going to spawn multiple date picker fragments overeach other if the picker is open during a configuration change. There must be sg. I'm missing.

Answer (score 101):

I couldn't get anyone of these working so will add my one just in-case it helps.

```
public class MyEditTextDatePicker  implements OnClickListener, OnDateSetListener {   
EditText _editText;
private int _day;
private int _month;
private int _birthYear;
private Context _context;

public MyEditTextDatePicker(Context context, int editTextViewID)
{       
    Activity act = (Activity)context;
    this._editText = (EditText)act.findViewById(editTextViewID);
    this._editText.setOnClickListener(this);
    this._context = context;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    _birthYear = year;
    _month = monthOfYear;
    _day = dayOfMonth;
    updateDisplay();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(_context, this,
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dialog.show();
    
}

// updates the date in the birth date EditText
private void updateDisplay() {

    _editText.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based so add 1
    .append(_day).append("/").append(_month + 1).append("/").append(_birthYear).append(" "));
}
}
```

Also something that isn't mentioned in the others. Make sure you put the following on EditText xml.

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Otherwise like in my case the Keyboard will keep popping up.

Comment: Awesome!! An addition : Won't work for fragment views. For Fragments change constructor argument to the EditText object rather than resource ID..

Comment: most be the answer

worked perfet I also added            `if(_birthYear!=0) calendar.set(_birthYear,_month,_day);` after Calendar calendar line to load last selected date when the user press again

Answer (score 25):

```
class MyClass implements OnClickListener, OnDateSetListener {   
   EditText editText;
   this.editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
   this.editText.setOnClickListener(this);
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

       DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, 2013, 2, 18);
       dialog.show();
   }
   @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
       // this.editText.setText();
   }
}
```

Comment: Make that onDateSet is not called inside On Click rather it should be called when construting the callBack object which should be passed as second paremetre   callBack = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),year+ " "+monthOfYear+" "+dayOfMonth,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        };

Answer (score 25):

Here's a Kotlin extension function for the lazy folks:

```
fun EditText.transformIntoDatePicker(context: Context, format: String, maxDate: Date? = null) {
    isFocusableInTouchMode = false
    isClickable = true
    isFocusable = false

    val myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val datePickerOnDataSetListener =
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.UK)
            setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.time))
        }

    setOnClickListener {
        DatePickerDialog(
            context, datePickerOnDataSetListener, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        ).run {
            maxDate?.time?.also { datePicker.maxDate = it }
            show()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

In Activity:

```
editText.transformIntoDatePicker(this, "MM/dd/yyyy")
editText.transformIntoDatePicker(this, "MM/dd/yyyy", Date())
```

In Fragments:

```
editText.transformIntoDatePicker(requireContext(), "MM/dd/yyyy")
editText.transformIntoDatePicker(requireContext(), "MM/dd/yyyy", Date())
```

Comment: @moyo I do not find any issues on the last android version. Check if you have some other configuration set on your project that is causing it.

Comment: This worked, but it is also setting the max date on the datepicker to the date(), how would you remove the maxdate?

Comment: don't pass maxDate argument in function transformIntoDatePicker

Comment: All `View`s have a `Context` accessible via `context`/`getContext()` internally, there is no need to add a parameter for context. Nonetheless, this is an elegant solution for selecting dates.

Answer (score 11):

There is another better reusable way as well:

Create a class:

```
class setDate implements OnFocusChangeListener, OnDateSetListener {   

       private EditText editText;
       private Calendar myCalendar;

       public setDate(EditText editText, Context ctx){
           this.editText = editText;
           this.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
           myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       }

       @Override
       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)     {
           // this.editText.setText();

            String myFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"; //In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            editText.setText(sdformat.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

       }

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
             new DatePickerDialog(ctx, this, myCalendar
                       .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                       myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Then call this class under onCreate function:

```
    EditText editTextFromDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFromDate);
    setDate fromDate = new setDate(editTextFromDate, this);
```

Comment: How should the class signature look: `class setDate implements View.OnFocusChangeListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {` ?

Comment: class setDate implements View.OnFocusChangeListener, TimePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

Comment: Your solution worked for me using a Fragment.  I simply changed "this" to "getContext()".

Comment: Also, you need to set a private variable and set it from the constructor.  "private Context ctx;".

Comment: Also, I was having some issues releasing the keyboard.  So, I added "v.clearFocus();" inside the onFocusChange handler.

Answer (score 10):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="DD/MM/YYYY"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="00:00"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

**JAVA FILE**

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText selectDate,selectTime;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        selectDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
        selectTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.time);

        selectDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        selectTime.setOnClickListener(this);




    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == selectDate) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            selectDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
        if (view == selectTime) {

            // Get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {

                            selectTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how I do it: Similar to the chosen answer, but using a static dialog class so it's more reusable, and also using onFocusChange instead of onClick.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet");
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.set(year, month, day);
                        editText.setText(df.format(c.getTime()));
                        nextField.requestFocus(); //moves the focus to something else after dialog is closed
                    }
                };
                datePickerFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        }
    });
```

And the datepicker dialog.

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        //blah
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The selected answer didn't quite work for me as I had to tap the EditText box once, and then tap it again before the OnClickListener would fire. I was able to fix this by replacing OnClickListener with OnTouchListener, just in case anyone has run into a similar issue here is what my code looks like:

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }

};
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            new DatePickerDialog(classname.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    }
});

private void updateLabel() {

    String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    edittext.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: This issue can also be fixed by this: editTextView.setFocusable(false);

Answer (score 7):

**#1. I want to show a datepicker with current date as preselected** (I use butterknife for injection)

```
  @OnClick(R.id.your_view) public void onClickYourView() {

    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        String myFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"; // your format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());

        your_view.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
      }

    };
    new DatePickerDialog(mContext, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

  }
```

## 2. If you want to preselect the date replace the last part with

```
new DatePickerDialog(mContext, date, 1990, 0, 1).show();
```

then you can get it using myCalendar variable or directly the text on your view.

Answer (score 4):

```
 selectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatePickerDialog  mdiDialog =new DatePickerDialog(mContext,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),year+ " "+monthOfYear+" "+dayOfMonth,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                }, year, month, date);
                mdiDialog.show();

            }

        });
```

Comment: I am not quite sure about it, may be there is another method you can override or you can concat

Comment: Last option is initializing a calendar with obtained year,month,and day and getting the date in required format

Comment: oh you can use a method   

private String get2DigitValue(int value){ return int>9?int+"":"0"+int}

Answer (score 4):

Using **DataBinding:**

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:focusable="false"
  android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onDateEditTextClicked()}"
  android:hint="@string/hint_date"
  android:imeOptions="actionDone"
  android:inputType="none"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:text="@={viewModel.filterDate}" />
```

(see `focusable`, `inputType` and `onClick`)

Inside **ViewModel:**

```
public void onDateEditTextClicked() {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Is this working for anyone? I tried using this approach but the onClick method is not being called. But when I write traditional onClickListener in viewModel, then it is working.

Answer (score 4):

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DatePickerHelper {

private final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
private final String dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
private TextView textView = null;

public DatePickerHelper(final Context context, TextView textView) {
    this.textView = textView;

    // Setup on click listener if the TextView is not null
    if (textView != null) {
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getDatePickerDialog(context).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Return a new date picker listener tied to the specified TextView field
 * @return
 */
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener getOnDateSetListener() {
    return new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.US);
            textView.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Return new DatePickerDialog for field
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
private DatePickerDialog getDatePickerDialog(Context context) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(context, getOnDateSetListener(), calendar
            .get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

}
```

Usage:

```
  DatePickerHelper assessmentDueDateHelper = new DatePickerHelper(AssessmentsDetailActivity.this,
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assessmentDueDateEditText));
```

Answer (score 4):

**Use this simple technique to do it :**

*Step 1 : CREATE A FRAGMENT DIALOG*

```
public class DatePickerFragmentDialog  extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day);
    }

}
```

*Step 2 : IN REQUIRED ACTIVITY FOLLOW THIS*

1. The activity must implement : **DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener**
2. Set onClickListener on a Button:

   ```
   DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragmentDialog();
   datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Custom Date Picker");
   ```

*Step 3 : Override OnDateSetListener*

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat dateFormat = new 
        SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        String currentDateString = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        tvPaymentDate.setText(currentDateString);
    }
```

Therefore we can use any formatting for the date :)

Answer (score 3):

A solution using fragments, MvvmCross, and Xamarin.Android

```
public class EnterTimeView : MvxFragment, DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
    {            
        private EditText datePickerText;
        public EnterTimeView()
        {
            this.RetainInstance = true;
        }

        public override Android.Views.View OnCreateView(Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            this.HasOptionsMenu = true;

            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.EnterTimeView, container, false);

            datePickerText = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.DatePickerEditText);
            datePickerText.Focusable = false;
            datePickerText.Click += delegate
            {
                var dialog = new DatePickerDialogFragment(Activity, Convert.ToDateTime(datePickerText.Text), this);
                dialog.Show(FragmentManager, "date");
            };

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<EnterTimeView, EnterTimeViewModel>();    
            set.Bind(datePickerText).To(vm => vm.Date);
            set.Apply();

            return view;
        }   

        public void OnDateSet(Android.Widget.DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            datePickerText.Text = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth).ToString();
        }

        private class DatePickerDialogFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment 
        {
            private readonly Context _context;
            private DateTime _date;
            private readonly DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener _listener;

            public DatePickerDialogFragment(Context context, DateTime date, DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener listener)
            {
                _context = context;
                _date = date;
                _listener = listener;
            }

            public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
            {
                var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(_context, _listener, _date.Year, _date.Month - 1, _date.Day);
                return dialog;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin port, call the setDatePicker function

```
private fun setDatePicker(dateEditText: EditText) {

    val myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    val datePickerOnDataSetListener = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
        updateLabel(myCalendar, dateEditText)
    }

    dateEditText.setOnClickListener {
        DatePickerDialog(this@YourActivityName, datePickerOnDataSetListener, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
    }
}

private fun updateLabel(myCalendar: Calendar, dateEditText: EditText) {
    val myFormat: String = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.UK)
    dateEditText.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.time))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Date Picker Dialog

```
                Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
                Integer month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                Integer day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                Integer year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =new DatePickerDialog(Expenture_Activity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        et_from.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                    }
                },year,month,day);
                datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried every way that was suggested but all of them have their own problems.

The best solution in my opinion would be to use a frame layout like below:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                .... />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/invisible_click_watcher"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and then adding the *DatePickerDialog* code which was beautifully written in @Android's answer.

Answer (score 2):

My class for show `DatePicker`. I can use for `EditText`, `TextView` or `Button`

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TextViewDatePicker
        implements View.OnClickListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    public static final String DATE_SERVER_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog;
    private TextView mView;
    private Context mContext;
    private long mMinDate;
    private long mMaxDate;

    public TextViewDatePicker(Context context, TextView view) {
        this(context, view, 0, 0);
    }

    public TextViewDatePicker(Context context, TextView view, long minDate, long maxDate) {
        mView = view;
        mView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mView.setFocusable(false);

        mContext = context;
        mMinDate = minDate;
        mMaxDate = maxDate;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_SERVER_PATTERN);
        mView.setText(formatter.format(date));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        if (mMinDate != 0) {
            mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mMinDate);
        }
        if (mMaxDate != 0) {
            mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mMaxDate);
        }
        mDatePickerDialog.show();
    }

    public DatePickerDialog getDatePickerDialog() {
        return mDatePickerDialog;
    }

    public void setMinDate(long minDate) {
        mMinDate = minDate;
    }

    public void setMaxDate(long maxDate) {
        mMaxDate = maxDate;
    }
}
```

Using

```
EditText myEditText = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
TextViewDatePicker editTextDatePicker = new TextViewDatePicker(context, myEditText, minDate, maxDate);
//TextViewDatePicker editTextDatePicker = new TextViewDatePicker(context, myEditText); //without min date, max date
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought it better to override the EditText class...

```
public class EditTextDP extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText implements View.OnClickListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    public EditTextDP(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnClickListener(this);
        setFocusable(false);
    }

    public EditTextDP(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnClickListener(this);
        setFocusable(false);
    }

    public EditTextDP(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setOnClickListener(this);
        setFocusable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append("/").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("/").append(year));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

And use that in the XML instead...

```
            <*.*.*.EditTextDP
                android:id="@+id/c1_dob_hm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/round_edittext_white"
                android:ems="10"
                android:padding="8dp">

            </*.*.*.EditTextDP>
```

Answer (score 2):

**USe this**

```
your_edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            String date = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)
                                    + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
                            your_edittext.setText(date);
                        }
                    }, yy, mm, dd);
                    datePicker.show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                      int dayOfMonth) {

                    int s = monthOfYear + 1;
                    String a = dayOfMonth + "/" + s + "/" + year;
                    editText1.setText(a);
                }
            };

            Time date = new Time();
            DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(UpdateStore.this, dpd, date.year, date.month, date.monthDay);
            d.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Using @DrunkenDaddy extension function, in my case at least (creating EditText programmatically), it was displaying the keyboard on first click and then the date picker on second click.

Apparently, it's irrelevant to set isFocusable and isFocusableInTouchMode to false, because first click is always interpreted as a focus change by the EditText. So I had to trigger a click when the EditText gained focus. Now it works as expected: on first click it opens directly the date picker and never the keyboard (thanks to setting showSoftInputOnFocus to false):

```
fun EditText.transformIntoDatePicker(context: Context, format: String = "dd/MM/yyyy", maxDate: Date? = null) {
    isClickable = true
    showSoftInputOnFocus = false
    isCursorVisible = false

    setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->  if (hasFocus) callOnClick()}

    val myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val datePickerOnDataSetListener =
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault())
            setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.time))
    }

    setOnClickListener {
        DatePickerDialog(
             context, datePickerOnDataSetListener, 
             myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
             myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        ).run {
            maxDate?.time?.also { datePicker.maxDate = it }
            show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a single function for all activities which when called will open date picker and then return my selected date then create one interface for all

```
public interface OnDatePickerLitionarCallBack {

    void DatePicker(String selectedDate);
}
```

after then call interface in activity

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnDatePickerLitionarCallBack {
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        findViewById(R.id.date_pick).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                date_Picker(MapsActivity.this,MapsActivity.this);
            }
        });
    }
     @Override
        public void DatePicker(String selectedDate) {
        
    
        }
    }
```

after implement interface create a common public class for access any activity or fragment

```
public class Commons{

    public static void date_Picker(Context context, OnDatePickerLitionarCallBack onDatePickerLitionarCallBack) {
        final java.util.Calendar myCalendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                String myFormat = "dd,MMM yyyy"; //In which you need put here
                java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
   
                onDatePickerLitionarCallBack.DatePicker(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

            }
        };
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, date, myCalendar
                .get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


        datePickerDialog.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DatePickerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    static TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_click);
        textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_date);



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment newFragment=new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datepicker");
            }
        });

    }

    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int  day) {
            String years=""+year;
            String months=""+(monthOfYear+1);
            String days=""+day;
            if(monthOfYear>=0 && monthOfYear<9){
                months="0"+(monthOfYear+1);
            }
            if(day>0 && day<10){
                days="0"+day;

            }
            textView.setText(days+"/"+months+"/"+years);


        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
            int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=null;
            datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year,  month, day);

            return datePickerDialog;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.chs);
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.datepickerdialog);
            dp=(DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btp);
            dialog.show();
            ok=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: would be helpful to have some explanation about your answer along with the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    String fmonth, fDate;
                    int month;


                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {


                        try {
                            if (monthOfYear < 10 && dayOfMonth < 10) {

                                fmonth = "0" + monthOfYear;
                                month = Integer.parseInt(fmonth) + 1;
                                fDate = "0" + dayOfMonth;
                                String paddedMonth = String.format("%02d", month);
                                editText.setText(fDate + "/" + paddedMonth + "/" + year);

                            } else {

                                fmonth = "0" + monthOfYear;
                                month = Integer.parseInt(fmonth) + 1;
                                String paddedMonth = String.format("%02d", month);
                                editText.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + paddedMonth + "/" + year);
                            }


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();


    }


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put these 4 lines on (EditText, AppCompatEditText). It will not show the keyboard. And then on clicklistener you can show the datePicker

```
android:clickable="false" 
   android:cursorVisible="false" 
   android:focusable="false" 
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Kotlin extension function for Material Date Picker:

```
fun TextInputEditText.datePicker(fm:FragmentManager, tag: String) {

isFocusableInTouchMode = false
isClickable = true
isFocusable = false

val datePicker =
    MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
        .setTitleText("Select Date")
        .build()


setOnClickListener {

    datePicker.show(fm,"tag")
}

datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
   setText(datePicker.headerText)
    Log.d("TAG", "datePicker: \n $it")
}}
```

Usage:

In Activity:

```
yourTextInputEditText.datePicker(supportFragmentManager,"tag")
```

In Fragment:

```
yourTextInputEditText.datePicker(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager,"tag")
```

Comment: The tag parameter is not used in the function, maybe it should be used in the call of datepicker.show inside the onclicklistener?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

DataPickerListener listener;

public DatePickerFragment(DataPickerListener l) {
    listener = l;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the date picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    month = month + 1;
    String stringOfDate = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
    listener.setDate(stringOfDate);
    Util.Log(stringOfDate);
}

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    listener.cancel();
}

public static interface DataPickerListener {
    void setDate(String date);

    void cancel();
}
}
// use this function to open datePicker popup

DialogFragment newFragment;

public void pickDate() {
    if (newFragment == null)
        newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(new PickDateListener());
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
}

class PickDateListener implements DataPickerListener {

    @Override
    public void setDate(String date) {
        createSpiner(date);
        onetouch = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        onetouch = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

             DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                   String date = i2 + "/" + (++i1) + "/" + i;
                   text.setText(date);
                }
        },year,month,date);
       }
    });  

    datePickerDialog.show();
```

you can also set the Minimum date and max date by these statements.

```
   datepickerDialoge.getDatepicker().setMinDate(long Date);

   datepickerDialoge.getDatepicker().setMaxDate(long Date);
```

Note:add these line before datepickerDialog.show(); statement
you will get date by like this=12/2/2017.

I Hope my answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Jan 2020

XML Part:

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etDOB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:editable="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Your Date of Birth" />
```

Java Part:

```
         final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

         userDOBView  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDOB);


    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
      @Override
      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int  dayOfMonth) {
             myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
             myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
             myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
             updateLabel();
      }
    };

    userDOBView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
         new DatePickerDialog("YourClassName".this, date, 
             myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
             myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),         
             myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
          }
          return true;
       }
    });
private void updateLabel() {
  String myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

  // edittext.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
  userDOBView.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: Don't post deprecated answers.

Answer (score -1):

My solution for Xamarin.Android with MvvmCross based on Linh's:

```
public class DatePickerEditText : EditText, DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
{
    IDisposable _clickSubscription;

    public override bool Clickable => true;

    protected DatePickerEditText(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer)
        => Init();

    public DatePickerEditText(Context context) : base(context)
        => Init();

    public DatePickerEditText(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) 
        : base(context, attrs)
        => Init();

    public DatePickerEditText(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) 
        : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        => Init();

    public DatePickerEditText(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) 
        : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
        => Init();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _clickSubscription?.Dispose();
            _clickSubscription = null;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
        => Text = view.DateTime.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);

    void Init()
    {
        SetFocusable(ViewFocusability.NotFocusable);
        _clickSubscription = this.WeakSubscribe(nameof(Click), OnClick);
    }

    void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var date = DateTime.Today;
        try
        {
            date = DateTime.Parse(Text, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context,
                                          this,
                                          date.Year,
                                          date.Month,
                                          date.Day);
        dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

For a vanilla Xamarin.Android version just replace the WeakSubscribe with a regular subscription to the EditText's Click event, not forgetting to unsubscribe in the Dispose method override.