# DatePickerDialog on EditText Click Event (running issue)

Tags: android, datepicker

I am implementing a fragment that have where I have an edittext  and I want to popup a date picker when I click on it
I used the following link

[Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933330/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-edittext/26225312#26225312)

But change the following:
I have added:
private static final String TAG = "AppoinFragment";
and
String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; 
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

And replace nextField.requestFocus();  with fullname.requestFocus();
When running my application and clicking on the edittext nothing happened.
Here is the code I used:

AppointFragment.java

```
package com.example.appointapp;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AppointFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = "AppoinFragment";
    EditText fullname;

    private Appointment mappoitnemnt;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mappoitnemnt= new Appointment();


}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_appoint, parent, false);



    fullname = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.datea_text);

    fullname.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet");
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.set(year, month, day);

                        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; 
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

                        fullname.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));

                        fullname.requestFocus(); 
                    }
                };
                datePickerFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        }
    });


    return v;
}
}
```

DataPickerFragment.java

```
package com.example.appointapp;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public  class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    }
}
```

Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Is there anything else on the Fragment?  It's possible that the EditText already has focus as such clicking on it won't trigger the listener.  Try swapping it for an OnClickListener instead

Comment: yes i have added android:focusable="false" beaccue someone wrote tht we should added it. when i removed it it works.Thank you so much for the help