# Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on button and store value in textview

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_arrival"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/arrivaldate"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_arrival"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Set"/>
```

I want to show datepicker popup window. I have found some examples but i am not getting it properly. I have one button and i want that when i click on button the datepicker dialog should popup and after setting the date, the date should be display in a . PLease provide me sample code or good links.

```
 btn_arrival.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog setDate = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                setDate.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                setDate.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_setdate);
                setDate.show();
                DatePicker date = (DatePicker) setDate.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
                date.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
                Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();

                DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener onDateChangedListener = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int years, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        day = dayOfMonth;
                        year = years;
                        month = monthOfYear;
                        setDate.dismiss();
                        txt_arrival.setText("Arrival Date on: " + day + "." + (month + 1) + "." + year);
                        tv_departure.setText("Departure Date on: " + (day + 1) + "." + (month + 1) + "." + year + "");
                    }
                };

                day = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                month = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                year = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                date.init(year, month, day, onDateChangedListener);

            }

        });
```

Comment: i am update my question with code

Comment: what exactly is not working? Showing the dialog or getting the value into textView?

Comment: when i click on set button it is put automatically the date the dialog  not display to chose the date that i want .

Comment: @Opiatefuchs showing the dialog not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the Sample code
set onclicklistener on your view like this

```
 Calendar dateSelected = Calendar.getInstance();
  private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
dateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           setDateTimeField() ;
        }
    });


private void setDateTimeField() {
    Calendar newCalendar = dateSelected;
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            dateSelected.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, 0, 0);
            dateEditText.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateSelected.getTime()));
        }

    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dateEditText.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateSelected.getTime()));
}
```

or you can follow this link

[Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933330/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around for an AlertDialog fragment for a DatePicker that on set, puts the date in to a TextView.

xml for DatePicker

You can omit the CardView root layout and use anything like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp"
card_view:cardElevation="24dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/date_time_title"/>

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:calendarViewShown="true"
        android:spinnersShown="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/date_time_not_set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="start"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set"
            android:layout_gravity="end"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

java file for activity/fragment

```
[...] //other code
btn_arrival.setOnClickListener( this );

// Activity/Fragment implements onClick()
@Override
public void onClick( final View v )
{
    switch ( v.getId( ) )
    {
        case R.id.btn_arrival: createDatePicker( tv_arrival); break;
    }
}

private void createDatePicker( final TextView tv_arrival )
{
    final View dialogView = View.inflate( getActivity( ), R.layout.date_picker, null );
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( getActivity( ) ).create( );
    TextView tv = ( TextView ) dialogView.findViewById( R.id.date_time_title );
    tv.setText( ); // set title here
    dialogView.findViewById( R.id.date_time_set ).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener( )
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view )
        {
            setDatePicker( dialogView, tv_arrival );
            alertDialog.dismiss( );
        }
    } );
    dialogView.findViewById( R.id.date_time_not_set ).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener( )
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v )
        {
            alertDialog.dismiss( );
        }
    } );
    alertDialog.setView( dialogView );
    alertDialog.show( );
}

 private void setDatePicker ( View dialogView, TextView tv_arrival )
{
    DatePicker datePicker = ( DatePicker ) dialogView.findViewById( R.id.date_picker );
    Calendar calendar;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH );
    calendar = new GregorianCalendar( datePicker.getYear( ), datePicker.getMonth( ), datePicker.getDayOfMonth( ) );
    tv_arrival.setText( sdf.format( calendar.getTime( ) ) );
}
```