# DatePicker not showing onClick of EditText in AlertDialog

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog

I need to show the `datePicker` to select date on click event of `EditText`, my `EditText` is in `AlertDialog`. I've written a code for `onClickListener`, but its not displaying the `datePicker`.

```
public class TourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper db;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tour);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            inflater = TourActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_new_trip, null);
            final EditText editEvent = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.edTxt_EventName);
            final EditText editStartDate = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.edTxt_EventSDate);

            editStartDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(TourActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");
                    mDatePicker.show();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TourActivity.this);
            builder.setView(content)
                    .setTitle("Add Event")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                        Tour tour = new Tour();

                                        tour.setEventId((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
                                        tour.setEventName(editEvent.getText().toString().toUpperCase());

                                        long t = db.createTour(tour);

                                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                                                "Event Added Successfully.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                .setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
                                                .show();

                                        displayList();
                                    }


                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
}public class TourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper db;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tour);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            inflater = TourActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_new_trip, null);
            final EditText editEvent = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.edTxt_EventName);
            final EditText editStartDate = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.edTxt_EventSDate);

            editStartDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(TourActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");
                    mDatePicker.show();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TourActivity.this);
            builder.setView(content)
                    .setTitle("Add Event")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                        Tour tour = new Tour();

                                        tour.setEventId((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
                                        tour.setEventName(editEvent.getText().toString().toUpperCase());

                                        long t = db.createTour(tour);

                                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                                                "Event Added Successfully.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                .setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
                                                .show();

                                        displayList();
                                    }


                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other piece of code.

Comment: Here is a solution for your answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933330/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-edittext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933330/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-edittext)

Comment: @MubinSayed appreciate your help!!! but my editText is not directly in activity its in AlertDialog which is why creating another dialog is a problem,.