# Select date and time from date picker popup

Tags: datetime, datepicker

How to Select date and time from date picker popup.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIb3m.png)

Comment: Add related tag like Android, iOS, Web, etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933330/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's duplicated : [Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933330/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-edittext)

Also, you can find many tutorial on internet ;

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html