# Android: Countdown Data app - how to change hard coded end date

Tags: java, android, xml

I've just started with Android Studio and built a simple date countdown app, the end date is hard coded, what I want is to be able to change this on the app itself without using Android Studio.

I've already got a button on the activity.main xml that I will use to set a new date.

Any ideas on how I can get it changed on the app?

Comment: Use a date picker to search for dates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933330/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-edittext