# Calender is not getting displayed when click on ediitext

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar, android-edittext

I refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14933515/12553303) answer, but onclick on edittext calender is not displaying... When click on eddittext it is working like a normal one like keyboard is displaying...

Can you explain where I'm wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    val myCalendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        val edittext1 = findViewById(R.id.dob) as EditText
        val date =
            OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth -> // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                val myFormat = "MM/dd/yy" //In which you need put here
                val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
                edittext1.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()))                }

        edittext1.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
           override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DatePickerDialog(
                    applicationContext, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                ).show()
            }
        })
```

ediitext code:

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/inputloginbox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/emailregister"
    android:id="@+id/dob"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:hint="dob"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon_reg"        />
```

**Note**: when i write `android:focusable="false"` it touch on edittext disappers

Comment: ```android:editable="false"```

Comment: @simon5678  this--> android:editable="false" doesnt do anything on edditext....touch disappears..nothing happend

Comment: @simon5678 and got depricated too

Comment: I tried ```android:focusable="false"```, and it works for me.

Comment: @simon5678 but it is not working in my case why?

Comment: What does ```it touch on edittext disappers``` mean?

Comment: when i touch on that edditext ..doesnt do anything..doesnt display anything @simon5678

Comment: Use this@MainActivity insted of applicationContext. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code, and it crashed.

Don't use `applicationContext` for Dialog. Use your Activity, for example, `this@MainActivity`.

Comment: i tried this@activity ..still doesnt displayed @simon5678

Comment: @wini Any exception?

Comment: how do i check that?

Comment: Did your app crashed? Watch the logcat window of Android studio.

Comment: Weird. When I used ```applicationContext```, my app crashed and logcat told me ``` android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?```

Comment: hey i sjust restarted studio..it worked...but when im posting the value of birthday using post request ..if i set today date and post retrofit call...it is displaying 01-01-1970 date ....whyyyyyy?

Comment: @Wini It means your date somehow become 0 value.

Comment: i raised new question --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147106/datepicker-value-from-edittext-using-retrofit-post-request