# Change date picker theme android java

Tags: java, android, datepicker, themes

So i got this from another question since i can comment, i am making the question as something new

```
 DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }

    };

    tv_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
```

the code on top does a date piker but i want a different theme i want "AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK"
but i dont know where to add this...

original solution fund here
[Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933330/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-edittext)